# How can I fix the GPS problem that occured after jailbreaking iPhone 3GS 4.2.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, gps

I have an iPhone 3GS (old bootrom) and updated to 4.2.1 via iTunes a few days ago. Then I jailbreaked it via redsn0w 0.9.6b6. I only marked the option to install Cydia, nothing else (i.e. I didn't updated the baseband to 6.15.00; in settings on the iPhone, it says I have 5.15.04).

Now, it seems that GPS is not working anymore. Why? How can I fix it?

If there is not really a way to fix it, what are the options? In any case, I must have GPS working and I must have the jailbreak.

Downgrade to 4.2 somehow? Or reset it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a copy of your old SHSH blobs. If you don't have it, I don't believe you will be able to downgrade.

If you have your old blobs, grab a copy of the older firmware and [follow](http://www.dkszone.net/downgrade-ios-4-2-1-4-1-iphone-43gs3g-ipod-touch-ipad) various [guides](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-downgrade-ios-4.2.1-to-4.1-4.0.2-4.0.1-on-iphone-4-3gs-3g-ipod-touch-and-ipad/)

Comment: if you have the copy @Albert, this is **the** guide: http://thebigboss.org/jailbreak-now

Comment: @Cawas - that link doesn't answer his question on how to downgrade or fix his GPS issue.

Comment: I meant to jailbreak, so he know which best version to downgrade to.